# How to use Observable.Generate to output in a console

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Why does the following code produce no output?

It's a console app to generate some random values (I am learning Reactive Extensions).

```
using System.Reactive.Linq;

static void Main(string[] args)
{   
    var rand = new Random();
    Observable.Generate(
        5.0,
        i => i > 0,
        i => i + rand.NextDouble() - 0.5,
        i => i,
        i => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1)
    ).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);  
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't have time to generate anything. Try adding `Console.ReadLine();` to the end.

Comment: @Blorgbeard It works now. What's the reason for that?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Rx, but I assume it's executing on a background thread. When the main thread exits, background threads are killed. When the `Main` function ends, the main thread exits. `Console.ReadLine()` waits for input on the main thread, so the background thread isn't killed until you press a key.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Ty. plz copy the answer so i can close the question.

Comment: If you save your observable in a variable, you also can call `observable.Wait()`. It waits/blocks until the Observable Complets executing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `Observable` represents an *asynchronous* data stream. Because you are passing a time-span to `Generate`, the number generation is happening in a background thread.

When your `Main` function exits, the main thread exits. When the main thread exits, background threads are killed.

Since your `Main` function will exit before 0.1 seconds has elapsed, your generator doesn't have time to generate anything. Try adding `Console.ReadLine();` to the end of your `Main` function, so the background thread isn't killed until you press a key.

Comment: Btw. the number generation only runs in a background thread if someone uses the Timing features of Rx. If Observable.Generate is only called with 4 parameters, then no background Thread is created, and the program will run on the main Thread in an endless Loop.

Comment: Thanks Sid, this is why I hesitated to post an answer - figured I would miss something like that.

Comment: An `Observable` represents a pub/sub source ***capable*** of asynchrony. Unlike promises and callbacks in Node.js, `Observable`'s are not by necessity asynchronous. Example: `Observable.Return`, and even `Observable.Generate` create synchronous `Observable`s, and many Rx operators also return an observable with the same synchronicity as the source for which they are operating. Example: `Select`, `SelectMany`, `Aggregate`, `Scan`, `Count`, etc. These *do* however include overloads to specify a scheduler, which *can* change the synchronicity of the operation.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris thanks for the clarification. I was going by [this documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/data/gg577609.aspx), which puts heavy emphasis on asynchronisity.